# SQL inner join dont work - syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I'm trying to use inner join to join id's in two tables.

Table students structure:

```
id first_name second_name last_name course
```

Table objects structure:

```
student_id math programming english history
```

My SQL statement

```
SELECT s.id, s.first_name, o.student_id 
FROM students s 
INNER JOIN objects o ON s.id = o.student_id
```

I'm getting error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' o.english, o.history FROM students s INNER JOIN objects o ON s.id = o.student_i' at line 1'

EDIT:

This is my code

```
$this->db = new Database();
        $q = $this->db->selectQuery('SELECT s.id,s.first_name,o.student_id FROM students s INNER JOIN objects o ON s.id = o.student_id');
        $data = $this->db->stmt->fetchAll($q);


function selectQuery( $sql ) {
        $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
        $this->stmt->execute();
    }
```

Comment: It appears that only a part of your SQL string is being sent. Please show the entire section of the program that triggers this error.

Comment: Your error mentions `o.english, o.history` as part of the query where as the your SQL statement doesn't - are you sure this is what you are trying to execute?

Comment: Edited the post. There is the code.

Comment: the message contains text `o.english, o.history FROM students`, but it's not in your query `s.id,s.first_name,o.student_id FROM`. When you receive an error you have run another query.

Comment: Try to tick objects, so it reads `objects`, it might be treating it as a reserved word

Comment: You sure? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6d1fe/1/0 works perfectly